# KCFinder - browse.php downloading rather than displaying page

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, upload, ckeditor

I've integrated the latest version of KCFinder into CKEditor - whenever I click the 'Browse Server' button on the CKEditor toolbar it opens the KCFinder dialog box and downloads the 'browse.php' file rather than display the contents of a directory.

It is almost as if for some reason the PHP engine stops working temporarily - i've not modified any of the htaccess files.

I'm currently using the standard config.php within the kcfinder directory - would anyone know what may have caused this and how to fix it?

// kcfinder/config.php

```
$_CONFIG = array(

'disabled' => true,
'denyZipDownload' => false,
'denyUpdateCheck' => false,
'denyExtensionRename' => false,

'theme' => "oxygen",

'uploadURL' => "",
'uploadDir' => "",

'dirPerms' => 0755,
'filePerms' => 0644,

'access' => array(

    'files' => array(
        'upload' => true,
        'delete' => true,
        'copy' => true,
        'move' => true,
        'rename' => true
    ),

    'dirs' => array(
        'create' => true,
        'delete' => true,
        'rename' => true
    )
),

'deniedExts' => "exe com msi bat php phps phtml php3 php4 cgi pl",

'types' => array(

    // CKEditor & FCKEditor types
    'files'   =>  "",
    'flash'   =>  "swf",
    'images'  =>  "*img",

    // TinyMCE types
    'file'    =>  "",
    'media'   =>  "swf flv avi mpg mpeg qt mov wmv asf rm",
    'image'   =>  "*img",
),

'filenameChangeChars' => array(/*
    ' ' => "_",
    ':' => "."
*/),

'dirnameChangeChars' => array(/*
    ' ' => "_",
    ':' => "."
*/),

'mime_magic' => "",

'maxImageWidth' => 0,
'maxImageHeight' => 0,

'thumbWidth' => 100,
'thumbHeight' => 100,

'thumbsDir' => ".thumbs",

'jpegQuality' => 90,

'cookieDomain' => "",
'cookiePath' => "",
'cookiePrefix' => 'KCFINDER_',

// THE FOLLOWING SETTINGS CANNOT BE OVERRIDED WITH SESSION CONFIGURATION
'_check4htaccess' => true,
//'_tinyMCEPath' => "/tiny_mce",

'_sessionVar' => &$_SESSION['KCFINDER'],
//'_sessionLifetime' => 30,
//'_sessionDir' => "/full/directory/path",

//'_sessionDomain' => ".mysite.com",
//'_sessionPath' => "/my/path",
```

);

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem and I found that the .htaccess file in the kcfinder dir was precisely shut the php engine off. I removed the .htaccess file and then it worked. I do not understand why this shutting off was necessary. Security?? 
Well, I still get a problem to point at the right directory, but now I see something !!

One comment here about the CONFIG array here above. The attribute disabled have to be put to false, and it is often suggested to be done through a SESSION variable (put `$_SESSION['KCFINDER'] = array();`
`$_SESSION['KCFINDER']['disabled'] = false;` after the session_start() ), and not directly in the config file.